# Angular - ng-model values assign to another ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angularJS.

I have two part.

1. Communication Address
2. Permanent Address

Each section have textbox as same field.

Also I have checkbox. Once  checkbox checked means the Communication address are assign to Permanent address.

I attached my code here. I tried its not workig. Can anyone suggest how to implement this?

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('firstCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.localAddress = {};
 $scope.permanentAddress = {};

 $scope.address = {
  value : false
 };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<h2 style="font-size: 18px;font-weight: bold;" > Communication Address
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
    
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
    <form class="tab-pane address" id="address" name="addressForm" rc-submit="addressState()" rc-step novalidate>
 
 <div class="x_content col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1">
  <div class="row ">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <label for="door_no">Door No</label>
      <input type="text" name="door_no" ng-model="localAddress.door_no" id="door_no"  class="form-control parsley-success" data-parsley-id="0951">
      <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-0951"></ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <label for="street">Street</label>
      <input type="text" name="street" ng-model="localAddress.street" id="street"  class="form-control parsley-success" data-parsley-id="0951">
      <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-0951"></ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row ">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <label for="location">Location</label>
      <input type="text" name="location" ng-model="localAddress.location" id="location"  class="form-control parsley-success" data-parsley-id="0951">
      <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-0951"></ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <label for="city">City</label>
      <input type="text" name="city" ng-model="localAddress.city" id="city" class="form-control parsley-success" data-parsley-id="0951">
      <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-0951"></ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row ">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <label for="district">District</label>
      <input type="text" name="district" ng-model="localAddress.district" id="district"  class="form-control parsley-success" data-parsley-id="0951">
      <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-0951"></ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <label for="state">State</label>
      <input type="text" name="state" ng-model="localAddress.state" id="state"  class="form-control parsley-success" data-parsley-id="0951">
      <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-0951"></ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row ">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <label for="country">Country</label>
      <input type="text" name="country" ng-model="localAddress.country" id="country"  class="form-control parsley-success" data-parsley-id="0951">
      <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-0951"></ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <label for="pin_code">Pin Code</label>
      <input type="text" name="pin_code" allow-pattern="[\d]" ng-model="localAddress.pin_code" id="pin_code" class="form-control parsley-success" data-parsley-id="0951">
      <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-0951"></ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row ">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <label for="contact_no">Contact No</label>
      <input type="text" minlength="10" maxlength="10" name="contact_no" allow-pattern="[\d]" ng-model="localAddress.contact_no" id="contact_no"  class="form-control parsley-success" data-parsley-id="0951">
      <input type="hidden" ng-model="localAddress.is_permanent_address_flag" ng-show="(localAddress.is_permanent_address_flag=false) ||1==1" class="form-control parsley-success">
      <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-0951"></ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="x_title">
  <h2 style="font-size: 18px;font-weight: bold;" > Permanent Address
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="address.value">{{address.value}}
  <span style="color:#73879C; font-size:15px">(Same as communication address )</span></h2>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="x_content col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1">
  <div class="row ">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <label for="door_no">Door No</label>
      <input type="text" name="door_no" ng-model="permanentAddress.door_no" id="door_no"  class="form-control parsley-success" data-parsley-id="0951">
      <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-0951"></ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <label for="street">Street</label>
      <input type="text" name="street" ng-model="permanentAddress.street" id="street"  class="form-control parsley-success" data-parsley-id="0951">
      <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-0951"></ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row ">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <label for="location">Location</label>
      <input type="text" name="location" ng-model="permanentAddress.location" id="location"  class="form-control parsley-success" data-parsley-id="0951">
      <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-0951"></ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <label for="city">City</label>
      <input type="text" name="city" ng-model="permanentAddress.city" id="city" class="form-control parsley-success" data-parsley-id="0951">
      <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-0951"></ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row ">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <label for="district">District</label>
      <input type="text" name="district" ng-model="permanentAddress.district" id="district"  class="form-control parsley-success" data-parsley-id="0951">
      <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-0951"></ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <label for="state">State</label>
      <input type="text" name="state" ng-model="permanentAddress.state" id="state"  class="form-control parsley-success" data-parsley-id="0951">
      <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-0951"></ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row ">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <label for="country">Country</label>
      <input type="text" name="country" ng-model="permanentAddress.country" id="country"  class="form-control parsley-success" data-parsley-id="0951">
      <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-0951"></ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <label for="pin_code">Pin Code</label>
      <input type="text" name="pin_code" allow-pattern="[\d]" ng-model="permanentAddress.pin_code" id="pin_code" class="form-control parsley-success" data-parsley-id="0951">
      <input type="hidden" ng-model="permanentAddress.is_permanent_address_flag" ng-show="(permanentAddress.is_permanent_address_flag=true) ||1==1" class="form-control parsley-success">
      <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-0951"></ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row ">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <label for="contact_no">Contact No</label>
      <input type="text" minlength="10" maxlength="10" name="contact_no" allow-pattern="[\d]" ng-model="permanentAddress.contact_no" id="contact_no"  class="form-control parsley-success" data-parsley-id="0951">
      <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-0951"></ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <!--               Address_Details   -->
</form>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the use of 
`is_permanent_address_flag` in your view ?

Comment: I need to differentiate communiation address and permenent address. so that is flag. also I need to maintain the state for checkbox check or not

Comment: you can get communication address from `$scope.localAddress` and permanent address from `$scope.permanentAddress` if I am not wrong ?

Comment: Yes. We can get from there.

Answer (score 0):

Do this changes

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="address.value" ng-change="copyCommToPerm()">
```

JS  in controller:

```
$scope.copyCommToPerm = function(){
      $scope.permanentAddress  = angular.copy($scope.localAddress)
    }
```

Comment: In this scenario - after checkbox checked when change the values in  Communication address means?

Comment: i am not getting you

Answer (score 0):

I updated your code please check it.It is working fine as per your requirement.

```js
   angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('firstCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.localAddress = {};
 $scope.permanentAddress = {};

 $scope.address = {
  value : false
 };
 $scope.IsAddressClone=function()
 {
 
   if ($scope.address.value) {
   
     $scope.permanentAddress = Object.assign({}, $scope.localAddress);
   
   }
   else
   {
      $scope.permanentAddress={};
   }
 }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<h2 style="font-size: 18px;font-weight: bold;" > Communication Address
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
    
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
    <form class="tab-pane address" id="address" name="addressForm" rc-submit="addressState()" rc-step novalidate>
 
 <div class="x_content col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1">
  <div class="row ">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <label for="door_no">Door No</label>
      <input type="text" name="door_no" ng-model="localAddress.door_no" id="door_no"  class="form-control parsley-success" data-parsley-id="0951">
      <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-0951"></ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <label for="street">Street</label>
      <input type="text" name="street" ng-model="localAddress.street" id="street"  class="form-control parsley-success" data-parsley-id="0951">
      <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-0951"></ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row ">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <label for="location">Location</label>
      <input type="text" name="location" ng-model="localAddress.location" id="location"  class="form-control parsley-success" data-parsley-id="0951">
      <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-0951"></ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <label for="city">City</label>
      <input type="text" name="city" ng-model="localAddress.city" id="city" class="form-control parsley-success" data-parsley-id="0951">
      <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-0951"></ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row ">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <label for="district">District</label>
      <input type="text" name="district" ng-model="localAddress.district" id="district"  class="form-control parsley-success" data-parsley-id="0951">
      <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-0951"></ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <label for="state">State</label>
      <input type="text" name="state" ng-model="localAddress.state" id="state"  class="form-control parsley-success" data-parsley-id="0951">
      <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-0951"></ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row ">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <label for="country">Country</label>
      <input type="text" name="country" ng-model="localAddress.country" id="country"  class="form-control parsley-success" data-parsley-id="0951">
      <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-0951"></ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <label for="pin_code">Pin Code</label>
      <input type="text" name="pin_code" allow-pattern="[\d]" ng-model="localAddress.pin_code" id="pin_code" class="form-control parsley-success" data-parsley-id="0951">
      <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-0951"></ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row ">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <label for="contact_no">Contact No</label>
      <input type="text" minlength="10" maxlength="10" name="contact_no" allow-pattern="[\d]" ng-model="localAddress.contact_no" id="contact_no"  class="form-control parsley-success" data-parsley-id="0951">
      <input type="hidden" ng-model="localAddress.is_permanent_address_flag" ng-show="(localAddress.is_permanent_address_flag=false) ||1==1" class="form-control parsley-success">
      <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-0951"></ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="x_title">
  <h2 style="font-size: 18px;font-weight: bold;" > Permanent Address
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="address.value" ng-change="IsAddressClone()">{{address.value}}
  <span style="color:#73879C; font-size:15px">(Same as communication address )</span></h2>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="x_content col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1">
  <div class="row ">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <label for="door_no">Door No</label>
      <input type="text" name="door_no" ng-model="permanentAddress.door_no" id="door_no"  class="form-control parsley-success" data-parsley-id="0951">
      <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-0951"></ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <label for="street">Street</label>
      <input type="text" name="street" ng-model="permanentAddress.street" id="street"  class="form-control parsley-success" data-parsley-id="0951">
      <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-0951"></ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row ">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <label for="location">Location</label>
      <input type="text" name="location" ng-model="permanentAddress.location" id="location"  class="form-control parsley-success" data-parsley-id="0951">
      <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-0951"></ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <label for="city">City</label>
      <input type="text" name="city" ng-model="permanentAddress.city" id="city" class="form-control parsley-success" data-parsley-id="0951">
      <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-0951"></ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row ">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <label for="district">District</label>
      <input type="text" name="district" ng-model="permanentAddress.district" id="district"  class="form-control parsley-success" data-parsley-id="0951">
      <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-0951"></ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <label for="state">State</label>
      <input type="text" name="state" ng-model="permanentAddress.state" id="state"  class="form-control parsley-success" data-parsley-id="0951">
      <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-0951"></ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row ">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <label for="country">Country</label>
      <input type="text" name="country" ng-model="permanentAddress.country" id="country"  class="form-control parsley-success" data-parsley-id="0951">
      <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-0951"></ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <label for="pin_code">Pin Code</label>
      <input type="text" name="pin_code" allow-pattern="[\d]" ng-model="permanentAddress.pin_code" id="pin_code" class="form-control parsley-success" data-parsley-id="0951">
      <input type="hidden" ng-model="permanentAddress.is_permanent_address_flag" ng-show="(permanentAddress.is_permanent_address_flag=true) ||1==1" class="form-control parsley-success">
      <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-0951"></ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row ">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <label for="contact_no">Contact No</label>
      <input type="text" minlength="10" maxlength="10" name="contact_no" allow-pattern="[\d]" ng-model="permanentAddress.contact_no" id="contact_no"  class="form-control parsley-success" data-parsley-id="0951">
      <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-0951"></ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <!--               Address_Details   -->
</form>


  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do these changes:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="address.value" ng-change="address.value ? setSame():setDiff()">
```

JS in controller:

```
$scope.setSame = function(){
//fired when checkbox is checked
  $scope.permanentAddress  = angular.copy($scope.localAddress);
}

$scope.setDiff = function(){
//fired when checkbox is unchecked, reset the permanent address
  $scope.permanentAddress  = {};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with your view :

```
minlenght="10"
```

should be changed to `ng-minlenght="10"` same follows for `maxlength` as well.

And what is `allow-pattern="[\d]"` as AFAIK there is [ngPattern](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern)

Here is the link to [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Rishii/pen/LNOLdb?editors=1010) that might work for you.

I look for changes made to first form and if it changes and if `checkbox` is ticked I copy it to lower form.
If by default user ticks the `checkbox` I copy to lowerform and then any changes made to first form are copied to lower form.
If `checkbox` is `unchecked` I will not copy at all.

```
$scope.IsAddressClone = function() {
   if ($scope.address.value) {
     $scope.permanentAddress = angular.copy($scope.localAddress);
   }
 }
 $scope.$watchCollection('localAddress', function(nv, ov) {
   if (nv !== ov) {
     $scope.IsAddressClone();
   }
 })
```